# creating assoc function in lisp that will find value from a-list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How can i create an assoc function that can find value from a-list. 
Can anyone help me on this as i don't know how it works and am new to lisp. 
Could you describe in steps.
I have already googled about it but couldnot find anything on creating the assoc function.

Comment: What's the matter with using the function [assoc](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_assocc.htm) that's already built into the language?  Or as a (not quite the same) alternative, `(find item alist :key 'car)`?  Tell us more about what you're trying to do, and why those options don't work for you, and what you've tried already.

Comment: **I have already googled about it but couldnot find anything on creating the assoc function.** -1 for lack of research effort.  A [Google search for `"defun assoc"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22defun+assoc%22) turns up a bunch of implementations.

Comment: Lacks effort. The question is poorly worded and shows no effort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic lisp operations are list eaters:

```
(defun some-function (list-to-consume perhaps-additional-args)
  (cond ((endp list-to-consume) <end-of-list-expression>)
        ((<predicate> list-to-consume perhaps-additional-args)
         <result-expression>)
        (t (some-function (cdr list-to-consume) perhaps-additional-args))))
```

Examples:

```
;; The predicate is the endp expression
(defun mylength (list &optional (len 0))
  (cond ((endp list) len)
        (t (mylength (cdr list) (1+ len)))))

;; A member function
(defun mymember (element list)
  (cond ((endp list) nil)
        ((equal (car list) element) list)
        (t (mymember element (cdr list)))))

;; Exchange an element with another in a list
;; notice how this builds up a list recursively
(defun exchange (list element replacement)
  (cond ((endp list) nil)
        ((equal (car list) element) (cons replacement (exchange (cdr list) element replacement)))
        (t (cons (car list) (exchange (cdr list) element replacement)))))
```

There are other more advanced ways to replace most list eaters with `loop` or higher order functions like `mapcar`, `map` and `reduce`, but if you are learning LISP you probably should be familiar with the list eaters first.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252531#252531

Comment: @uselpa I have voted to close this to not clutter the site. I'll consider you comment for next time.